# updating dialog static text is not working

Tags: mfc

mfc(Cdialog):

```
//CImgView.cpp:
void CImgView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint pt)
{
    CPoint ptImg = GetScrollPosition() + pt;
    sprintf(sbuf,"X %d Y %d", ptImg.x, ptImg.y);
    ((CImgDlg*)GetParent())->Update1();
    CScrollView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, pt);
}
//CImgDlg.cpp:
void CImgDlg::Update1()
{
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_xy, sbuf); 
}
```

static text,IDC_STATIC_xy, does not get updated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that a dialog is the parent of CImgView, so GetParent is probably getting some other window. Try and provide a pointer to the CImgDlg object that can be saved in CImgView so it can call pImgDlg->Update1().

Comment: Try "Update1();"
instead of "((CImgDlg*)GetParent())->Update1();"